# How do I get a signal to call a function with certain arguments?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to get a signal to call a function with certain arguments, like the example below.

```
QPushButton *yes = new QPushButton("Yes");
yes->connect(yes, SIGNAL(clicked()), NULL, SLOT(printf("You pressed a button")));
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very inefficient but you could create a new signal with a `QString` argument, which you connect to your pushbutton. The text contained will be defined on your emit call.

eg.

```
connect(yes, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(emitHelloWorldText());
connect(this, SIGNAL(emitText(QString)), receiver, SLOT(dostuffWithText(QString)));
```

then your `emitHelloWorldText` method can be something like

```
void emitHelloWorldText() {
    emit emitText("Hello world");
}
```

Then this can be picked up by your receiver class

```
void doStuffWithText(const QString &text) {
```

Comment: This is horrible. The next step is that `emitHelloWorld` actually gets some text to emit from a GUI element.

Answer (score 2):

An often overlooked way to reverse signal/slot relationships is [QObject::sender](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender). You can call it in the receiving slot to get a handle on the `QPushButton` (using `qobject_cast`) and get the text from there. Alternatively you can use [QSignalMapper](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) to augment signals.

Comment: Using sender() is never a clean solution though, as it breaks the decoupling by assuming a certain sender in the slot.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld So does forwarding the slot through an intermediary. Just in another place. The Qt signal and slot mechanism is just a little weak as soon as you leave the predestined paths.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the slot and the signal must have matching arguments. If you really need to stick with this interface, you could create an intermediary slot to propagate the received signal, but there’s no real way around.